# Why is the $this->getOrders method always returns a null object in this code Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, sales-order

I am new to magento.I am trying to create a view for the purchase history for users.Already there is a page to display this(As I am using a template).But as a experiment I tried to create a new page with the same content.As my first step. I created a new php block and then I copied same the content from the old purchase history file to the new one**(Without any change)**.Then I called that block in a cms page.But when I called the url of the new page,It gives this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on null in
>   /home/bvbellpm/public_html/newtrades/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/purchasehistory.phtml
>   on line

This is the code which I used to display the history

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $_orders = $this->getOrders(); ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('My Orders') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
<?php if($_orders->getSize()>0): ?>
<table class="data-table" id="my-orders-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Order #') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Date') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Ship To') ?></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Total') ?></span></th>
            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Order Status') ?></span></th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $_odd = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
            <td><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()) ?></span></td>
            <td><?php echo $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $this->htmlEscape($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
            <td><em><?php echo $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></em></td>
            <td class="a-center">
                <span class="nobr"><a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
                    <?php /*<span class="separator">|</span><a href="<?php echo $this->getTrackUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></a>&nbsp;*/ ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('sales/reorder')->canReorder($_order)) : ?>
                    <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getReorderUrl($_order) ?>" class="link-reorder"><?php echo $this->__('Reorder') ?></a>
                <?php endif ?>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But this same code works fine in the  old purchase history file.Why is this not working in the new page? .I think **$this->getOrders()** is returning a null object.But it is working fine in the old page.As far as I know **$this->getOrders()** is a magic method in Magento.So I think it can be used any  where.Can someone explain me the reason for this odd behavior?

Comment: please add your layout and block file

Comment: Hello try this<?php if (sizeof($_orders->getItems()) > 0): ?>

Comment: Birjitsinh Zala  I tried it.But still it gives the error

Comment: Is there any thing I have to do in order to use getItems() method?.Do I need to define it in a xml file.Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

As you told us that you are new I would like to tell you about block and template mapping

Every template assign to a block so in template (phtml) file $this represent block class

so in your block class should have to contain that method `getOrders` other wise you will not get the data

You can look at this blog and learn how you bind blocks with template via layout http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/22/magento-part2-series-layouts/

Comment: K thanks for your support.I very much appreciate it

Comment: In the cms page I have coded like this. {{block type="core/template"  template="customer/form/purchasehistory.phtml"}}  Is it okay?

Comment: @sadeeenadeee, no In core/template block you dont have 'getOrders' method

Comment: So ,how are we going to know which block is having that method?. Can you tell me the folder path where core/template is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)) : ?>
```

Instea of this code`

```
<?php if($_orders->getSize()>0): ?>`
```

Comment: I tried it ,but it did't fix the issue

Comment: <?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)) : ?>

Comment: Still it gives  that error

Comment: need to check php of your block where you get collecton